# suspend_thread suspend took 200 ms, which is more than the allowed 200 ms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have xamarin forms project. this occurs sometimes, When sending requests from android to server or saving data in sqlite,
not always and cannot detect in which situations and why. any help?

Comment: Are you getting this on a physical device or an emulator?

Comment: both situations

Comment: Can you post the stack trace